# work done in observer frame

Tags: forces, reference-frames, friction, work

I had a few questions.
1) Is work done independent of the refrance frame?

2) Suppose a cart-A with rough surface is accelerating with an acceleration *a* and another cart-B with acceleration *b*. Now to calculate the work done by friction  on an object placed on cart-A if the friction coefficient is k. I changed the observer to the cart with acceleration b. Now in this accelerating refrence frame, how to calculate the work done?( masses are Ma and Mb respectively ).

3) If we assume ground refrence frame will the answer change and if yes, how?

Thanx in advanced.